# Cannot find './lib' for mongoose Heroku

Tags: heroku, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack app that I can't upload to heroku due to the error:

Cannot find './lib/' for mongoose or some module.

I have no idea why this is a problem or how to fix it. The application works fine on localhost but heroku does not want to take the application over this insignificant issue.

Here are my logs:

```
$ heroku logs -n 150 --app mathverter
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.017786+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! node v0.12.7
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.018160+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.018421+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.018584+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Mathverter@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.018711+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Exit status 1
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.018877+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019020+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Failed at the Mathverter@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019163+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Mathverter package,
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019294+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! not with npm itself.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019414+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019535+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019784+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     npm owner ls Mathverter
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019664+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! You can get their info via:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.019925+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.022292+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.784910+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.785828+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:45.773738+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:47.763035+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `npm start`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:49.741626+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m > Mathverter@0.0.0 start /app
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:49.741602+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:49.741628+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m > node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:49.741629+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.072254+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.077867+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053472+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:338
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053478+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     throw err;
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053479+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.077988+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053481+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module './lib/'
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053482+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053483+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053485+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053486+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at require (module.js:384:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053487+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js:7:18)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053488+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053490+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053491+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053492+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.067627+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.053493+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.072963+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! node v0.12.7
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.072734+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "sta
rt"
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.073400+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.073786+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Mathverter@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.073613+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.073923+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Exit status 1
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074068+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074218+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Failed at the Mathverter@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074493+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! not with npm itself.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074366+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Mathverter package,
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074623+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074747+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.075143+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.074871+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! You can get their info via:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.075014+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     npm owner ls Mathverter
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.077584+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.785433+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2015-09-20T07:19:50.772782+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[33m2015-09-20T07:32:55.507451+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mathverte
r.herokuapp.com request_id=de6a5664-77ef-4086-9051-1c704acc841c fwd="162.242.10.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[33m2015-09-20T07:32:57.442161+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" hos
t=mathverter.herokuapp.com request_id=e734aa20-adfd-43bd-a0b8-f961971b282f fwd="162.242.10.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
←[32m2015-09-20T07:34:33.332655+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v12 created by mikeyjm14@gmail.com
←[32m2015-09-20T07:34:33.332544+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy 0afa73e by mikeyjm14@gmail.com
←[35m2015-09-20T07:34:33.418096+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation started
←[35m2015-09-20T07:34:33.418111+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:33.884081+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:35.807701+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `npm start`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.677570+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.677590+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m > Mathverter@0.0.0 start /app
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.677592+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m > node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.677593+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992221+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:338
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992226+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     throw err;
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992227+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992229+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module './lib'
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992231+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992232+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992233+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992234+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at require (module.js:384:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992235+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js:7:18)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992237+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992238+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992240+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992241+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.005366+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.010488+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! node v0.12.7
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.010274+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "sta
rt"
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:37.992239+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.010859+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011120+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011277+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Mathverter@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011406+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Exit status 1
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011688+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Failed at the Mathverter@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011841+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Mathverter package,
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.009827+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.012210+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.012090+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011965+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! not with npm itself.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.015234+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.015349+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.012332+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! You can get their info via:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.012457+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     npm owner ls Mathverter
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.012577+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.014952+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.011551+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.686484+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.696577+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:38.697704+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:40.978464+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `npm start`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.075173+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.075200+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m > Mathverter@0.0.0 start /app
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.075202+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m > node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.075203+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570428+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m module.js:338
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570434+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     throw err;
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570436+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m           ^
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570438+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Error: Cannot find module './lib'
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570440+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570441+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570443+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570444+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at require (module.js:384:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570446+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js:7:18)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570447+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570448+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570450+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570451+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.570453+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.588426+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.595199+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.595786+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "sta
rt"
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.603961+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.596062+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! node v0.12.7
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.604145+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.596760+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.597235+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.597802+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Exit status 1
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.597579+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Mathverter@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.598044+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.598250+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Failed at the Mathverter@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.598464+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Mathverter package,
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.598666+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! not with npm itself.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.598853+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.599272+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! You can get their info via:
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.599044+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.599454+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR!     npm owner ls Mathverter
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.599655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:43.603468+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:44.385194+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
←[36m2015-09-20T07:34:44.373825+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[33m2015-09-20T07:35:09.695223+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mathverte
r.herokuapp.com request_id=62ea033b-9748-40b9-990b-17e186b365a4 fwd="162.242.10.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
←[33m2015-09-20T07:35:11.294891+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" hos
t=mathverter.herokuapp.com request_id=f7ac8bd9-0510-49ad-b03e-a1385e4c9b25 fwd="162.242.10.35" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction to solving this issue, I appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and debugging through the source tree terminal via Heroku commands for hours, I reinstalled mongoose and added mongoose and its current version to the list of dependencies in the package.json. Not sure why Heroku was having an issue with mongoose for it was not listed after npm installation in the package.json in a previous project I did.

[image: my package.json]